# PostgreSQL master-slave replication redirecting writes to master

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Master replication being set-up and certifiably functioning, the need is to be able to re-direct users write actions to the master from the slave, otherwise :

```
PG::ReadOnlySqlTransaction: ERROR:  cannot execute UPDATE in a read-only transaction
```

My understanding of M-S replication may be wildly off base... But having not found parameters that deal with directing writes to master server, I assumed it was part of the underlying functions defined in each `postgresql.conf` file.

How can update/create be passed by the slave to the master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot! PostgreSQL does not have the ability to redirect writes to master node, hence the slave will only accept read-only transactions.

One tool that acts as a middleware and can do load balancing of read-only statements between master and the slaves, but also redirecting write commands/transactions to master is [PgPool-II](http://www.pgpool.net/). If you can make your application to differentiate (through different data sources, for instance) read-only and read-write transactions, the performance will be better though and you can redirect read-only to a TCP load balancer.

Comment: Yes.  Makes sense => as write functions could be attributed to individual models for a given slave and postgreSQL would have no way of knowing that.